JMeter: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ls/DocumentLS after Java Version upgrade form Oracle 1.8 to OpenJDK 17
I recently upgraded Java version from 1.8(Oracle) to 17(OpenJDK), but post this activity, I am unable to launch JMeter and getting below exception:

How to resolve this issue?


Use jmeter.bat startup script, it adds all the necessary JVM startup options
According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.6.3 or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at JMeter Downloads page


If it doesn't help:

try adding --add-modules java.xml to your JVM startup arguments
get xerces jar and drop it to JMeter Classpath

